# Delete file stream from memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, filestream

Sounds like a duplicate, but I couldn't find any related solution, I'm developing a desktop application where users upload files to a server via HTTP. The application works great, but it uses too much memory since I have to open a `FileStream` of the file in order to upload it.

I've tried calling `.Dispose()` and `using (var fs = File.Open(path, mode)){}`, but obviously it doesn't free the memory, just deletes objects.

I also tried with:

```
GC.Collect();

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And works, but I've read that call the garbage collector is not a good practice and can affect the application performance. What I want to do is simple.

1. I read the file.
2. I upload the file.
3. I delete the file (from memory).

How can I do that?

Comment: "but it uses too much memory". What is your evidence of this? What are the symptoms? Do you simply have a different opinion from that of the GC?

Comment: Users have an upload limit of 512mb, so I tried by uploading a big file, and when I look at the task manager the used memory increases and remains like that (after the process) When I used the GC, happends the same BUT the memory decreases from 530 mb (the whole file size + the used memory) to 20 mb, it works as I expect but I doubt if use it or not

Comment: @neo You have proven that the memory will be deallocated when the garbage collection happens by calling `GC.Collect()`. So now you know that once the conditions for garbage collection are met, the memory will be deallocated (note that this isn't very often and usually only when memory is low)

Comment: It's quite likely that the problem is with your uploading code, which you didn't post.

Comment: If you're really are getting memory problems them perhaps you need to look at Streaming the file, rather than completely buffering it into memory. Have a look at MemoryMappedfile and its ViewAccessor. You can have a thread read 512kb chunks, upload and read the next chunk from the file by moving the accessor along. Couple Megabytes tops.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `Close()` the `FileStream` when you're through with it.

A common approach is to use `using` instead of managing this yourself:

```
using(var input = File.Open(filename))
{
   // use input to read/upload/etc

} // input gets closed (via IDisposable.Dispose() here)
```

Provided the FileStream is closed properly, the file's data will get cleared from memory by the GC automatically.

If your goal is to reduce the memory usage, a different approach may be required.  Instead of reading the entire file into memory and uploading it, you may want to read and upload in chunks (stream the results), or something similar.

Comment: @neo please note that garbage collection isn't instant, and doesn't happen as frequently as you might think. More info [here](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fee787088(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=LbuGUrSGAce3iQem8YDwAg&usg=AFQjCNFPgVzStIESvkrA9ibjFywA0C9Tiw&sig2=oJ0HSRBCSKhTjdOb1sTOdw) under 'Conditions for Garbage Collection'

Comment: @Neo How big, or how many files are you sending? IF you use the above approach garbage collector will free up the memory when it is needed.

Comment: @Neo you may misunderstand the answer, the code shows a common approach which completely replaces the `Close()`.

Comment: @Neo Yes, but you need to either call Close(), or call Dispose() explicitly, or wrap in a using like I demonstrated.

Comment: @alexw Thank's for share the link, well I guess I will leave that work to the garbage collector or follow the Reed's alternative..